# how to display pictures from a database using delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I want to display pictures stored in an MS Access database in a currently running program, where the person running the program will be able to see all of the pictures at the same time (maybe scroll up and down) and choose one of their choice.

I don't know the code

Please help, I'm still a high school student.

Comment: Better for you to do your own work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless all of the pictures are BMPs, Delphi won't help you much here. Although it has a `TDBImage` component, it only supports BMPs in your version(s) of Delphi, and it can only show one picture at a time anyway.

To do what you are asking, you will have to load the pictures manually.  Do your query, such as with `TADOQuery`, and then loop through the results, using `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` and `TGraphic.LoadFromStream()` to load each picture. You would have to look at a picture's raw data header to decide which `TGraphic` class to use (`TBitmap`, `TJPEGImage`, `TGifImage`, etc), load it from the database blob, and then display it as needed, such as in a `TImage`, an owner-drawn `TListView`, etc.  Repeat for each picture.

There are tons of examples and tutorials about this, if you look around.  This is off-topic for StackOverflow.